# Sizing a high-res image (~8MB) to display entirely in a small div (circular, diameter 100px)

Tags: html, css, image, thumbnails

First of all, thank you so much for being patient with what I know is a simple question that anybody with more than a couple of weeks' experience could figure out.  I've seen folks persevere and be very helpful on here and I hope you're willing to do that with me.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/65uzf/

Here is one of the places that I searched for answers on here: ([Vertically center image thumbnails into fix-sized div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284517/vertically-center-image-thumbnails-into-fix-sized-div))
I tried the solutions on there and it didn't work out for me.  I've also searched ~4 or 5 others, and been unsuccessful with those, too.

What I want to do is take a large image (what is linked as the background-image for the #ysypic and #tabpic divs) and display a thumbnail version of that image in the confines of the divs that I have set up for it.  As is, using the background properties that I have laid out in CSS, only a portion of the image displays inside of the circular divs.  Without these properties, the display defaults to an even smaller section of the image [presumably the pi*(50^2) area in the top left] with terrible resolution.

I do not care if the entire image doesn't display inside of the circles (it won't, given the difference in shape), and the overflow not being displayed is fine.  But I want to be able to see the figures in the center of each image, and not just a little portion of their heads.

Please inform me if this method of using background-image is not even the best approach, too.  I want to be able to do this elsewhere, i.e. taking large versions of images and displaying them small inside of a  significantly smaller than their normal resolution.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
<script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="piccontain">
            <div id="ysypic">
                <a href="www.thejourneytothebest.com/ysyprofile" class="guanyin" style="background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/lbarYwr.jpg')"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="piccontain">
            <div id="tabpic">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/KLZAkVC.jpg');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:100% 100%;

}
.container {
    text-align:center;
}
.piccontain {
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:10%;
    display:inline-block;
}
#ysypic {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    margin-left:25px;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/lbarYwr.jpg');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#tabpic{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    margin-left:25px;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/yj4ROnn.jpg');
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: BTW, your `<a href="">` is wrong. It should start with `http://`, as in `<a href="http://www.thejour`... instead of just "www".

Comment: @Dai: almost. it should better start with `//www.jour...`, so that HTTPS is used if the site was requested using HTTPS. (and if the site doesn'T use https yet, there is no harm done not specifing the protocol either...)

Comment: Aha.  Well, considering that I haven't bought the domain yet, it doesn't link anywhere, anyway.  But I'll fix it.  I'm trying not to use that solution, anyway, since it was the one from the other stackoverflow thread that I posted, and simply use background-image in the divs named above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with an image tag and overflow property :

```
.test{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    margin-left:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.test img{
     width:150px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-left:-30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5FkL/

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That looks very solid, thank you.  My inclination was to use background-image because I have read that in general, if it's part of the styling and not part of the content, it is best to code something in CSS rather than HTML, and have also heard that copious image tags can lead to longer load times.  But since an image tag and a background-image property are both a unique HTTP request, and this will be just a simple homepage, I guess that point is somewhat moot here.

Comment: I think I'll go with the image tags, thank you.  They seem to be easier to format all in all.

Comment: Generally talking, I would say yes for CSS better than HTML. But CSS background does not allow lot of manipulation as it is not a DOM element. I will have a look for full CSS but I doubt finding a good solution.

Comment: I came up with a css way to do it, if you want have a look.
http://jsfiddle.net/t5FkL/2/

Comment: Now I feel silly for not fiddling with the CSS positioning a bit more.  I think that when I would do the background-position:center property-value pair, it would place the image way away from the focus of the div, and all that I really had to do was move it around.  Thank you for your persistence.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: The issue still is it is really hard to reproduce for the second image in CSS, the img tag way is a bit more global thought.

Comment: No worries, nice images and nice design concept :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to stick with the img tag.  It is much easier to format.

Comment: Thanks.  It's an art and writing project that a friend and I are doing together.  Hopefully I can get it up and running in the next couple days.